# SQL Queries using EXISTS and OR operator

Tags: sql, subquery, exists

I have 4 tables

```
    users
    |  id  |Username|
    |   1  |  John  |
    |   2  |  Mike  |
    |   3  |  Alex  |

    user_contacts
    | user_id  |contact_id|
    |   1      |    2     |
    |   1      |    3     |
    |   2      |    3     |

    contact_groups
    | id  |  Group name  |
    |  1  |    Group 1   |  
    |  2  |    Group 2   |
    |  3  |    Group 3   |

    user_contact_groups
    | user_id  |contact_group_id|
    |   1      |    1           |
    |   1      |    2           |
    |   3      |    2           |
```

what id like to do is to pull users which belongs to Contact Group 1 and 3 or a contact of user 1 (in table:user_contacts). Below is code, but it returns query is empty

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.* from  users as a 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_contacts as b 
    WHERE b.user_id = 1) OR 
    (a.id IN (select c.user_id 
         FROM user_contact_groups as c 
            WHERE c.contact_group_id IN (1,3)));
```

Comment: This should always return all the rows from your `users` table, as the first condition in your WHERE clause is effectively a `1=1`.

Comment: The user_id varies. i should replace the 1 with %d . Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I would do it, and should be the most optimal:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*
FROM users u
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_contacts c ON u.id = c.contact_id 
    AND c.user_id = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_contact_groups g ON u.user_id = g.user_id 
    AND g.contact_group_id IN (1,3)
WHERE c.id IS NOT NULL OR g.id IS NOT NULL
```

If you wanted to use EXISTS, you can of course turn this around, but the query may not be able to use indexes (you can remove the DISTICT for this query):

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM user_contacts c 
    WHERE c.contact_id = u.id
    AND c.user_id = 1
)
OR EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM user_contact_groups g 
    WHERE g.user_id = u.user_id
    AND g.contact_group_id IN (1,3)
)
```

I suggest doing an EXPLAIN and see which one is better for your RDBMS.

Comment: Brilliant!. I have made changes in my table above and tried to remove the last where clause in your code WHERE c.id IS NOT NULL OR g.id IS NOT NULL... but stil query is empty . thanks

Comment: It works!!. I had an error in my code and fixed it.Thanks for the help.!

Comment: This is the code that works for me : SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM users as a LEFT JOIN user_contacts as b ON a.id = b.contact_id AND b.user_id = %d LEFT JOIN user_contact_groups as c on c.user_id = a.id AND c.contact_group_id IN (%s) WHERE b.user_id IS NOT NULL OR c.user_id IS NOT NULL

Comment: @user1917451 Sure, just be careful the `%s` never comes from user input (or can be changed by malicious users using GET or POST variables). You might be better off using query parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing subqueries you could do left joins

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*
FROM users as a
LEFT JOIN user_contacts as b ON a.id = b.user_id AND a.id = 1
LEFT JOIN user_contact_groups as c on c.user_id = a.id AND c.contact_group_id IN (1,3)
WHERE b.user_id IS NOT NULL OR c.user_id IS NOT NULL
```

I don't have SQL in front of me to test this, but I think it'll get the right results

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have updated the table above. sorry my bad.

Comment: @user1917451 I've updated my answer. No real change required, just checking a different field in the where clause

Comment: This is weird, im still getting 


    SQL  : 
ERROR: Query was empty
. Same result with other answers.. hmm

Comment: It works!!. I had an error in my code and fixed it. Also it should be a.id = 1 :)... Thanks for the help.!

Comment: `a.id = b.user_id` so it doesn't matter which one you check - they have to be the same. The join to user_contacts is simply to check that a user_contact exists.